# Playwright Donet Execute Multiline Javascript

Tags: c#, playwright

How can I execute this javascript in playwright dot net

```
var checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]');
            for (var i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++) {
            if (checkboxes[i].type == 'checkbox')
                checkboxes[i].checked = true;
                }
```

tried this

```
await page.EvaluateAsync(@"async () => { var checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll('input[type='checkbox']');
            for (var i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++)
                if (checkboxes[i].type == 'checkbox')
                    checkboxes[i].checked = true; }  });");
```

I get error

```
Microsoft.Playwright.PlaywrightException: 'SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list
at eval (<anonymous>)
at UtilityScript.evaluate (<anonymous>:192:30)
at UtilityScript.<anonymous> (<anonymous>:1:44)'
```

Comment: What did you try so far?

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
        var checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]');
        for (var i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++) {
        if (checkboxes[i].type == 'checkbox')
            checkboxes[i].checked = true;
        }
```

Comment: how is this different than how i posted it?